# Method of calculating an average from statistically insignificant sample

Tags: mean, small-sample

I am collecting weather data from a region that has a 10 weather stations placed around it. The stations collect data such as temperature highs and lows, amount of precipitation, etc. Some of these stations provide daily weather data, however for whatever reason, there are days when the weather was not recorded in different stations. Instead of relying on a single weather station, I would like to use an average to generalize the temperature and precipitation for the region and then use that information to find correlations in other things (ie sales). Should I be using a mean calculation of the different measurements for this purpose?

Comment: What is "statistically insignificant sample"?

Comment: I'm talking about the weather station data